# Convert List<> or List<List<>>

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, converters

I need to convert a point of one class type (this type is from a 3rd party api) to a point of another class type of my own making.

The following works:

```
MyPointClass myPnt = new MyPointClass(ApiPointClass apiPnt);


public class MyPointClass
{
    public double X { get; private set; } = 0;
    public double Y { get; private set; } = 0;
    public double Z { get; private set; } = 0;

    public MyPointClass(ApiPointClass apiPnt)
    {
         //X, Y, Z values of MyPointClass are determined and stuffed into properties.
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to convert the following without loops?

```
    List<ApiPointClass>
or
    List<List<ApiPointClass>>
or
    ApiPointClass[]
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is impossible to process any kind of collection without a loop. You somestimes can avoid having to write the loop yourself, but there will be a loop - no questions asked.

Comment: No Linq commands or something similar, then?

Comment: automapper might help

Comment: @EdwardBagby Linq is just going to do the loop for you. It still - of coruse - does a loop.

Comment: @Christopher Fair enough. I suppose I should have been more explicit and said "...so I do not need to write a loop."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you had an IEnumerable called apiPnts, you could potentially do this if you reference System.Linq

```
apiPnts.Select(point => new MyPointClass(point)).ToList();
```

The point variable is an object of ApiPointClass and the Select internally does the iteration.

In this case, this returns a list of MyPointClass.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8

It applies to an array, or a list, but not a list of lists.  A list of lists would be different.

Comment: I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: For a list of lists you'd just use `SelectMany(l => l.Select(p => new MyPointClass(p))` instead.